# HTML validator reporting errors saying that ID already defined

Tags: html, css, validation

I did below to have different words have different font sizes in a large DIV box.
HTML validator is throwing error messages at me and I don't understand why. What is wrong with below code?

MY CSS:

```
#fsize1 {
        font-size: 26px;   
        color: #ffffff;
}

#fsize2 {
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#fsize3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;   
}

#fsize4 {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#fsize5 {
    font-size: 14px;   
    color: #ffffff;
}

#fsize6 {
    font-size: 11px;  
    color: #ffffff;  
}

#fsize1, #fsize2, #fsize3, #fsize4, #fsize5, #fsize6 {
   margin-right: 7px;
}
```

MY HTML

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com" class="box1">
<div id="fsizes"><span id="fsize3">aaaaaaaa</span><span id="fsize5"> 
bbbbbbbbb</span><span id="fsize2">ccccccccccccc</span>
<span id="fsize6">ddddddddddddddddddddd</span><span
id="fsize1">eeeeeeeeeeeeee</span><span id="fsize4">fffffffff</span></div></a>

<a href="http://www.mysite.com" class="box2">
<div id="fsizes"><span id="fsize1">aaaaaaaa</span><span id="fsize2"> 
bbbbbbbbb</span><span id="fsize4">ccccccccccccc</span>
<span id="fsize3">ddddddddddddddddddddd</span><span
id="fsize5">eeeeeeeeeeeeee</span><span id="fsize6">fffffffff</span></div></a>
```

Comment: Did you try searching to see what the error means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two divs with the id "fsizes" and two spans with the id "fsize3".

If you want them to both have the same reference in css, then you should give them the same class name, not the same id.

To use the class selector in css just replace the "#" with "."

Comment: Hi, it was a stupid mistake i see now. Thanks for the clear explanation, its resolved now.

Comment: No problem, if this helped resolve your issue, please mark this as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you have the same id in **at least two places** (though my guess is everywhere)
you have `<span id="fsize3">` here:

```
<span id="fsize3">aaaaaaaa</span>
```

and here:

```
<span id="fsize3">ddddddddddddddddddddd</span>
```

the html [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) says this is invalid:

> id = name [CS] This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name
>   must be unique in a document

Answer (score 1):

id shouldn't be assigned twice in a html file. Both your divs have id `fsizes`. Consider changing the id to a class, and change your css file from `#fsizes` to `.fsizes`

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Javalsu mentioned, you also have spans with the same ID's too. I would change your span ID's to classes if you plan on using them like you have in the OP.

For example, in the html:

```
<span class="fsize3">aaaaaaaaaa</span>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
SPAN.fsize3 { //do something; }
```

or

```
.fsize3 { //do something; }
```

I would have added this as a comment to Javaslu's, but it's not letting me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same ID for multiple elements in your code.

In HTML the ID attribute is used to identify a single, unique element. If you wish to apply same style rules to several elements, you better define a group of elements by using the attribute class on the elements you want to group.

HTML

```
<div id="first-element" class="fsize1"></div>
<div id="second-element" class="fsize1"></div>
<div id="third-element" class="fsize1"></div>
```

CSS

```
.fsize1 {
    font-size: 26px;   
    color: #ffffff;
}
```